# patterns symbol in regular expression

Tags: regex

I am new to regex,

Can anyone explain for me the patterns:

```
(<form[^\a]*</form>|<FORM[^\a]*</FORM>)
(method="[a-zA-Z]*|METHOD="[a-zA-Z]*)
```

Comment: RegEx Explainer link: `http://regexper.com/#(%3Cform%5B%5E%5Ca%5D*%3C%5C%2Fform%3E%7C%3CFORM%5B%5E%5Ca%5D*%3C%5C%2FFORM%3E)(method%3D%22%5Ba-zA-Z%5D*%7CMETHOD%3D%22%5Ba-zA-Z%5D*)%0A`

Comment: what does None of a means ? if a not in form !? or what ?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/7883415/4464570

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://myregextester.com/index.php# (enter pattern in the field `Match pattern` and make sure you have ticked `Explain`. then click <kbd>Submit</kbd>):

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    <form                    '<form'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\a]*                   any character except: '\a' (alarm) (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    </form>                  '</form>'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    <FORM                    '<FORM'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\a]*                   any character except: '\a' (alarm) (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    </FORM>                  '</FORM>'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                           '\r\n'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    method="                 'method="'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]*                any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
                             (0 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    METHOD="                 'METHOD="'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]*                any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
                             (0 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                           '\r\n'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: any character except: '\a' (alarm) (except a how ?? how can be (a) letter in form) ?

Comment: i mean <form  action="addarticle.php"  method="post"><input type="text" name = "name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" ></form> something like that there's a in "name" ?? it means except this a ??

Comment: The pattern `[^\a]*` gets evaluated and means that it matches a character different from the special character `\a` which is usually not printable but some kind of control character. Therefore that does not make much sense to me either. And the `*` means that this part may appear 0 times, once or any other number.

Answer (score 1):

Two great resources for RegExp: [Debugexx](https://www.debuggex.com/) and [regular expressions <sub>101</sub>](https://regex101.com/)

```
(<form[^\a]*</form>|<FORM[^\a]*</FORM>)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

<sub>[Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/PMDZu-GJ3B_dfL60)</sub>

[image]

<sub>[regular expressions <sub>101</sub>](https://regex101.com/)</sub>

---

```
(method="[a-zA-Z]*|METHOD="[a-zA-Z]*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

<sub>[Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ae9bZHgeIyMkM4yq)</sub>

[image]

<sub>[regular expressions <sub>101</sub>](https://regex101.com/)</sub>